# Are there fixed-width float types in clang?

Tags: c, clang

GCC provides _Float32 and _Float64 for fixed-width floats.

However, these are not standard, and don't exist in clang. I also can't find the equivalents for clang.

Some platforms can define float or double to not be 32 or 64 bits, so using these types is not an option.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Why do you want to use non-standard types? And unless you're actually and explicitly target platforms with unusual sizes for the floating point types, the chances of your code ever being built for such a platform is slim to none.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: There are real and obvious benefits to fixed-format types, so we do not need OP to answer these questions to address this problem. Having a fixed-format type enables us to reduce the variation in programs between platforms. Engineering principles derive asserted results from specifications, meaning that we say a program **will** behave in a certain way **because** the documentation of the things it uses provides us certain guarantees. Relying on “the chances” of something occurring is not engineering.

Comment: On the other hand, is simply the width of the type a sufficient specification, or should it be, for example, the IEEE-754 32-bit float? Is there a platform that has the IEEE-754 32-bit float available, but where it isn't `float`, and is still acceptable to use (which software emulation of the type might not be)? It would seem to me that if the exact specs of the type matter, the suitable type should be determined in a pre-compilation step. (That being said, I don't know if GCC's `_Float32` is defined more specifically than just being 32 bits in size.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, there are indeed real benefits that can be obtained from explicit-width types, but that does not obviate Some's question, because we don't know whether the OP is in fact seeking any of those particular benefits.  Inasmuch as indeed there *aren't* any standard explicit-width floating-point types, it is useful to know what the OP is trying to achieve in order to suggest an appropriate alternative.

Comment: And that alternative could plausibly be that the program relies upon `double` and `float` to be represented in IEEE 754 binary 64-bit and 32-bit floating formats, respectively, and documents that as a requirement on the implementation on which it runs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: It is pretty clear. When somebody asks how to use printf to format some particular way, we generally do not question what their real problem is. That is a suitable question to ask (to clarify a problem, not just for curiosity) when something is weird about a problem, not when it falls in line with normal goals. Asking about fixed-format floating-point types may not be as clear, but it is pretty clear.

Comment: are f32 f64 anything which could be used here?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I require these specific types because I'm implementing a specification that requires this exact behaviour. This behaviour *must* be the same across platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question as posed, [CLang's documented language extensions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) do not include analogs of GCC's `_Float32` and `_Float64` types.  Do note, however, that *even GCC* provides those only on targets that support corresponding types natively.

On the other hand, inasmuch as clang is built on top of LLVM, it is worthwhile to consider [LLVM's documentation of FP type representations](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#floating-point-types):

> The binary format of half, float, double, and fp128 correspond to the
>   IEEE-754-2008 specifications for binary16, binary32, binary64, and
>   binary128 respectively.

In that sense, then, CLang's equivalents of `_Float64` and `_Float32` are `double` and `float`, respectively.  (Indeed, the same equivalence holds in GCC for substantially all targets where the explicit-width versions are supported.)

Comment: does that mean double and floats are always 64 and 32 bits for clang?

Comment: @Revolver: yes, and for any annex F conforming C implementation, i.e. all interesting ones.

Comment: @R.. This comment + this answer is what helped me find the solution. Annex F does indeed specify the widths of the float and double types.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. They're called `float` and `double`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the C standard does not dictate that a float *must* be 32 bits, only that it is at least 32 bits. For my purposes, it must be exactly 32 bits.

Comment: @GUIpsp, the standard does not even specify that `float` must be at least 32 bits, ***unless*** the implementation defines the macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`, thereby declaring support for IEC 60559, aka IEEE 754 2008.  Note well, however, that historically, it has been fairly common for implementations to fail or decline to define that macro, yet still provided (at least) IEC 60559 representations for `float` and `double`.  Which may be sensible, because Annex F contains behavior specifications, too, and those are not as consistently followed as are the data formats.